# Types 'std::string' and 'const char[2]' are not compatible

Tags: c++, xcode, c++17, clion

I am using the following compiler:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I am running this version of MacOS:

```
10.15.4
```

I am using this version of `CLion`:

```
CLion 2020.1.1
Build #CL-201.7223.86, built on April 29, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.6+8-b765.40 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.4
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1987M
Cores: 6
Registry: run.processes.with.pty=TRUE
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.intellij.clion-swift, org.toml.lang, org.rust.lang
```

Here is the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(clion_error)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -pedantic-errors -Wshadow -Wstrict-aliasing)

add_executable("clion_error" main.cpp)
```

Here is `main.cpp`:

```
#include <string>

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::string my_string = "hello";

    return 0;
}
```

Here is how to reproduce the error:

1. Click `Code` in the top menu
2. Click `Inspect Code...`
3. Click `OK`

Here is the error I get:

`Types 'std::string' and 'const char[6]' are not compatible`

Why is this error being reported?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Do you have `#include <string>`? Is it an actual compiler error, or something that only shows up in the IDE?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/25nwPF

Comment: @ThomasSablik I have clarified the question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ThomasSablik I have rewritten the question.

Comment: I don't have access to a Mac with CLion. I tried it exactly as described on Linux Ubuntu Budgie with CLion 2020.1.1. I don't know if the compiler is related to the code inspection. I'm using gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0. I'm not able to reproduce the problem. I inspected the code and got 1 warning and no errors. The warning is _The value is never used_. That's a correct warning. Your problem looks like a bug in CLion for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [regression](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-19877) with CLion 2020.1 indeed. The problem only occurs when running code analysis via `Code | Inspect Code` or when disabling clangd server.